# access level for php

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables `student`, `instructor`, and `admin`, each one of them contains `id, username, password, email` and `access_level`. The `access_level` for the student is `1`, instructor is `2`, and admin is `3`. I want to filter the login to different pages, so each user will direct to different page. I have been looking and searching for answer but unfortunately nothing that help me.

Comment: Use conditionals on the pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
if (valid($username,$password) > 0) {
    //setcookie
    //setsession

    if (valid($username,$password) == 1) {
        //redirect to student page
    }

    else if (valid($username,$password) == 2) {
        //redirect to instructor page
    }

    else {
        //redirect to admin page
    }
}

else {
    //redirect to login
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I belive that you are buiding a erp application for school/college/institute and this is always a problem for the different access level login. There might be following options for your problem.

1. You can use single table for different login **Admin/Instructor/Student** with an extra field of type if you want OR use the access_level field to differentiate the different type of use. With this option you can use single login form and single login logic because you have to check username and password. If user is authenticated then use the access level in the condition to redirect user to the appropriate page and use the access level on every page to check if he/she is authentic to use this page or not.
2. Use different tables for different login (as you are saying in your question) and In the login form give a drop-down according to role **(Admin/Instructor/Student)** and check the login information in the appropriate table selected by the user and according to access_level redirect the user to appropriate page and save the **access_level** in session for further use, to check if user is authentic to access this page or not.

Ultimately you have to use access_level saved in session for checking the **access/redirection**. and to check you can use simple if/else condition with the **access_level**.

Answer (score 0):

this is my code
[this is the function that check the username and password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh5Ka.png)

[and here is the second part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXSqP.png)

Comment: One side note about the question in your code. You should pass the connection object to your class method by object'c constructor.